# Tkinter unable to write to text file

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I'm trying to write a program that is a recipe book that lets you add recipes etc. I'm fairly new with Python and Tkinter though.

```
#New Recipe Screen
def click(key):
    new_recipe = Tk()
    new_recipe.title("New Recipe")
    itemtext = Label(new_recipe, text="Item").grid(row=0, column=0)
    input_item = Entry(new_recipe).grid(row=0, column=1)
    quantitytext = Label(new_recipe, text="Quantity").grid(row=1, column=0)
    input_quantity =Entry(new_recipe).grid(row=1, column=1)
    unittext = Label(new_recipe, text="Unit").grid(row=2, column=0)
    input_unit = Entry(new_recipe).grid(row=2, column=1)
    fin_btn_text = "Finish"
    def write(x=fin_btn_text):
        click(x)
        dataFile = open("StoredRecipes.txt", "w")
        dataFile.write(str(input_item, ) + "\n")
        new_recipe.destroy

    finish_btn = Button(new_recipe, text=fin_btn_text, command=write).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is specifically the cause of your problem, but you must not create a Tkinter widget, grid it, and assign the result all on one line. All of your itemtext, input_item, quantitytext, input_quantity, unittext, input_unit variables are None. Create and assign on one line, then grid on a second line.

Comment: Also, you are opening the file in write mode.  This will truncate it (erase what it contained originally).  Are you sure you don't want append mode (`open("StoredRecipes.txt", "a")`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You are not closing the file when you are done with it.  Some systems require you to do this in order to commit the changes.  Either call `dataFile.close()` at the end of your `write` function or use a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file (which will automatically close it when you are done):

   ```
   def write(x=fin_btn_text):
       click(x)
       with open("StoredRecipes.txt", "w") as dataFile:
           dataFile.write(str(input_item, ) + "\n")
       new_recipe.destroy()  # Remember to call this
   ```
2. As @Kevin noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281291/python-tkinter-unable-to-write-to-text-file/27281374#comment43031254_27281291), you cannot call `.grid` on the same line as you create a widget.  The `.grid` method works in-place and always returns `None`.  Thus, it should be called on its own line after you create the widget:

   ```
   itemtext = Label(new_recipe, text="Item")
   itemtext.grid(row=0, column=0)
   ```